# browseURL function is not working in GCP AI notebook

Tags: python, r, google-cloud-platform, rpy2, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am trying to run GLM function of rstanarm library. I am using rpy2 library to connect python with R packages. Following is the code:

```
glm_post = rstanarm.stan_glm(formula, data=r_dataframe, prior=my_prior,iter=niter, chains=nchains, cores=cores)
```

But I am getting this error in GCP AI Notebook:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    197                 kwargs[r_k] = v
    198         return (super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self)
--> 199                 .__call__(*args, **kwargs))
    200 
    201 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    123             else:
    124                 new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2rpy(v)
--> 125         res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
    126         res = conversion.rpy2py(res)
    127         return res

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py in _(*args, **kwargs)
     43 def _cdata_res_to_rinterface(function):
     44     def _(*args, **kwargs):
---> 45         cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
     46         # TODO: test cdata is of the expected CType
     47         return _cdata_to_rinterface(cdata)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    675             )
    676             if error_occured[0]:
--> 677                 raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
    678         return res
    679 

RRuntimeError: Error in utils::browseURL(paste0("file://", sinkfile_html)) : 
  'browser' must be a non-empty character string
```

Comment: Please could you provide the instance type of the notebook you have created? Is it R 3.6? Additionally it would be useful to have a expanded version of your code, which included the import statements and any other additional information regarding the exception thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding this line in the env.sh file I was able to bypass the browseURL error.

`export R_BROWSER="false"`

Answer (score 2):

`browseURL()` is an R function trying to open a web browser to show the content at an URL. The GCP AI notebook is running on the cloud, and the system it runs on probably does not have a web browser set.

You'll need to find a way to call the R function `stan_glm()` in a way that does not make it require a web browser.

Comment: @Igautier Do you have any idea how to do that?